# Can't compile glibc for 64 bit system

Tags: glibc, assembly

I'm trying to compile glibc-2.16 statically for x64 system,

```
../configure --enable-kernel=2.6.9 --prefix=/run/shm/libc-static-64 --enable-static --enable-shared --host=i486-linux-gnu --build=i486-linux-gnu -q
```

Then I got:

```
configure: WARNING:
*** These auxiliary programs are missing or incompatible versions: sed
*** some features will be disabled.
*** Check the INSTALL file for required versions.
configure: error: the assembler must support TLS
```

In config.log I saw:

```
configure:354: checking for i386 TLS support
configure:376: gcc -c -g -O2 conftest.s 1>&5
conftest.s: Assembler messages:
conftest.s:8: Error: @TLSLDM reloc is not supported with 64-bit output format
conftest.s:8: Error: junk `@TLSLDM' after expression
conftest.s:9: Error: relocated field and relocation type differ in signedness
conftest.s:10: Error: relocated field and relocation type differ in signedness
conftest.s:11: Error: relocated field and relocation type differ in signedness
conftest.s:12: Error: @GOTNTPOFF reloc is not supported with 64-bit output format
conftest.s:12: Error: junk `@GOTNTPOFF' after expression
conftest.s:14: Error: @NTPOFF reloc is not supported with 64-bit output format
conftest.s:14: Error: junk `@NTPOFF' after expression
configure:379: $? = 1
configure:387: result: no
configure:390: error: the assembler must support TLS
```

Did I pass in wrong parameters?

Comment: I believe `glibc` just can't be compiled as a static library. At least not all of it.

Comment: @vonbrand It works for 32bit.

Comment: Fix the missing/out of date `sed` before continuing. Make *very* sure all build requirements are satisfied. And check the build instructions carefully, they aren't trivial nor typical.

Answer (score 2):

I got this error as well when building glibc-2.15.

Turns out it's because I had the --build configure flag wrong, so glibc's configury brought in a 32-bit sysdep directory that doesn't work in 64bit mode.  I see you're doing something similar; I was trying to set it to i686-pc-linux-gnu instead of i486, but same difference.  Try a 64-bit target triple instead.

I went with whatever ../glibc-2.15/scripts/config.guess printed (x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu on my system, but run it yourself and see) and it seemed to successfully configure.  I believe the first chunk is the important one (x86_64).